# How to get Databricks aes_encrypt to give the same output for the same input

Tags: aes, databricks

I have a need to encrypt some data in Databricks. I'm currently using the built in aes_encrypt function.  If I use the sql shown below, I get a distinct value for each record in the table.  I do not get the same value for the encrypted value when the same input is used.

Is there a way to encrypt data in Databricks so the same input yields the same output?

```
drop table if exists encr;
create table encr as (
select 
  original_text,
  base64(aes_encrypt(original_text,'abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef')) as encrypted, 
  cast(aes_decrypt(unbase64(base64(aes_encrypt(original_text,'abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef'))), 'abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef') as string) as decrypted
from
  my_table
)
;
```

Results:

```
select 
  count(*),
  count(distinct original_text),
  count(distinct encrypted)
from
  encr
;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting the mode to 'ECB' gets the same output for the same input:
https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/aes_encrypt.html

```
drop table if exists encr;
create table encr as (
select 
  original_text,
  base64(aes_encrypt(original_text,'abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef','ECB')) as encrypted, 
  cast(aes_decrypt(unbase64(base64(aes_encrypt(original_text,'abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef'))), 'abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef') as string) as decrypted
from
  my_table
)
;
```

Comment: Note that encrypting non-random data with ECB is incredibly insecure. In some cases it barely qualifies as encryption. https://words.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/  In most cases, getting distinct cipher text for every encryption is an key part of the system and removing it substantially degrades, and in some cases destroys, its security.